# What are the most used functional forms for utility in RBC literature, and why?

Tags: macroeconomics, new-keynesian-economics, rbc

In the RBC/NK literature one has to define a functional form for the utility function of the representative household. What are the most used forms, and why are they used?

Any help would be appreciated